# Suddenly System.UnauthorizedAcessException on one device

Tags: android, xamarin.android, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am debugging my Xamarin.Android App alternately with 2 devices

- **Samsung Galaxy Tab A (Android 9) 10" Tablet**
- **Huawei Honor 8 (Android 8) 5.2" Smartphone**

On my MainLauncher-Activity the user is directly asked for the Permission (*Camera, RecordAudio, ReadExternalStorage, WriteExternalStorage, etc.*)

After the permission-check the App writes a new entry to the logfile. 
Everything just works fine on all devices until now (10th September 2019)

On my Huawei Honor I get a **System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to path is denied.'**

[image]

I haven no idea how to approach this error.

- reinstall and regrand the permission does not help (same process on Tablet leads to no errors)

**Only Android 9 still works!**

- **Lenovo Yoga Tab3 Android 6 - ERROR**
- **Samsung Galaxy  Android 7.1 - ERROR**
- **Huawei Hono 8 Android 8 - ERROR**
- **Huawei MediaPad M5 Android 8 - ERROR**

---

- **Samsung Galaxy Tab A Android 9 - WORKS FINE**
- **Samsung Galaxy S10 Android 9 - WORKS FINE**

yesterday, all devices worked fine

---

**EDIT:**
I could fix this problem with the workaround mentioned in this Thread
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3426

Using

```
var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(tempfile);
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileBytes);
```

instead of

```
File.Copy(tempfile, filePath, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(tempfile);
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileBytes);
```

instead of

```
File.Copy(tempfile, filePath, true);
```

is a workaround for this issue.
You can find an open discussion here

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3426

Comment: You can accept your answer ,which will help more people .